# Не создаётся процесс через CreateProcess()

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Есть некий процесс с параметрами, который должен корректно запускаться и останавливаться из NT-сервиса. Попробовал два варианта его запуска с помощью CreateProcess().

Вариант 1:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
LPSTR lpPrName = "bash.exe";
LPSTR lpParam = "start_demon.bash";
CreateProcess(lpPrName, lpParam, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

В этом случае `GetLastError()` возвращает ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.

Вариант 2:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
LPSTR lpPrName = "bash.exe";
LPSTR lpParam = "start_demon.bash";
char Cmd[255];
sprintf_s(Cmd, "%s %s", lpPrName, lpParam);
CreateProcess(NULL, Cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

В этом случае процесс вроде как запускается, однако процесса с таким PID'ом я нигде не наблюдаю.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А StartupInfo si вы где/когда инициализируете?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, да прямо перед объявлением имени процесса

Comment: Код инициализации добавьте, пожалуйста. Иногда бывают досадные ошибки.

Comment: Код неполный. Без кода инициализации структур можно долго гадать в чем проблема.

Comment: Виноват, добавил.

Comment: Я могу быть неправ, поскольку пытаюсь сделать это в терминале, плюс в Delphi, но без выставления флагов si, например, так: si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
    si.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL; меня тоже отфутболивает, хотя не должно. Если же флаги выставлены - всё  в порядке

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, увы, не помогло. Ещё выяснил, что даже во втором варианте вылезает ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS, хотя проверку возвращаемого значения CreateProcess() проходит...

Comment: "процесс вроде как запускается, однако процесса с таким PID'ом я нигде не наблюдаю" - так может он просто сразу падает с ошибкой. Прав доступа, например, не хватает к чему-то из под аккаунта, в котором работает сервис

Comment: @Erlas: Если "проверку возвращаемого значения CreateProcess() проходит", значит ваше `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` не имеет никакого отношения ни к `CreateProcess`, ни к рассматриваемой проблеме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась достаточно тривиальной - процесс bash, который я пытался запустить, требовал указания точной дорожки к скрипту, указываемому в параметрах. Т.к. NT-сервис не имел своего консольного окна, то я просто не видел сообщений о такой ошибке. Всем спасибо за содействие.